# интерфейсы runnable и callable

Tags: java

Чем отличаются два интерфейса для реализации задач `Runnable` и `Callable`? Какая необходимость иметь оба, если `Callable` может делать все, что делает `Runnable`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Интерфейс Callable похож на Runnable, поскольку оба они предназначены
>   для классов, экземпляры которых потенциально выполняются другим
>   потоком. **Однако Runnable не возвращает результат и не может выставить
>   проверенное исключение.**

Информация взята из документации - [ссылка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).