# Вернуть массив данных в основной класс из потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Пытаюсь получить список открытых портов в локальной сети, но без знания работы потоков это сложно. Не могу понять как извлечь данные из каждого потока и объединить их в массив для возврата в родительский класс. Пример кода ниже опрашивает хосты запуская проверку для каждого хоста в отдельном потоке и это работает в сотни раз быстрее чем делать запрос последовательно, но вот вернуть данные в `Main` класс у меня не выходит. Любая помощь или совет пригодятся мне.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scaner scaner = new Scaner();
    scaner.scaner();
    System.out.println("DONE!");
    }
}

class Scaner {
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 7000;
    List<String> ip_list_with_open = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    public void scaner(){
        for (int i = 0; i<255; i++) {
            String ip = "192.168.43."+i;
            int port = 80;

            Runnable task = () -> {

                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket();
                    SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(ip,port);
                    socket.connect(address,TIMEOUT);
                    //OPEN
                    System.out.println(ip+":"+port+" = OPEN");
                    ip_list_with_open.add(ip);
                    socket.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    //WRONG ADRESS
                    System.out.println(ip+":"+port+" = WRONG ADRESS");
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    //TIMEOUT
                    System.out.println(ip+":"+port+" = TIMEOUT");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //CLOSED
                    System.out.println(ip+":"+port+" = CLOSED");
                }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут нужно доделать 3 вещи:

- вы используете непотокобезопасную коллекцию `ArrayList`, из-за этого при добавлении в неё элементов из разных тредов (потоков) результат непредсказуем. Надо заменить на потокобезопасную, например, обернуть в `synchronizedList`:

  ```java
  List<String> ip_list_with_open = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
  ```
- вы не дожидаетесь окончания работы всех тредов. Надо их собрать в список (тут уже можно не потокобезопасный, т.к. работа с ним будет только из одного треда) и *после* завершения основного цикла сделать ещё один цикл, где пройтись по ним и для каждого вызвать `thread.join()`
- ну и чтобы вернуть результат, надо поменять тип возвращаемого значения у метода `scaner` на `List<String>` и в конце сделать `return` вашего списка:

  ```java
  public List<String> scaner() {
      //...
      return ip_list_with_open;
  }
  ```

  Тогда в методе `main` можно будет получить этот результат, типа `List<String> ips = scaner.scaner();`

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. А тот факт что я использую Runnable вместо Callable, это может сработать?

Comment: @Jonathan ну в данном коде замена `Runnable` на `Callable` ничего не изменит. Точнее, это вообще не сработает, т.к. `Thread` не принимает на вход `Callable`. Тогда уж надо на executor-ы и future переписывать

Answer (score 1):

`Runnable` не возвращает результат, нужно использовать `Callable`

Подробнее об этом:

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811233/интерфейсы-runnable-и-callable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811233/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8B-runnable-%D0%B8-callable)